# Frame borders in the LibreOffice Impress

Tags: libreoffice

I'm preparing big poster for the presentation using LibreOffice Impress. Within it there are several blogs (paragraphs) consisted of the some text and images on which my poster has been divided. I'm looking for the possibility to introduce fancy ornaments (e.g frames or border for each blog. I'll be very thankful if someone provide me with it as well as some short tutorials considering posters preparation in Impress.

Thanks for help,

Gleb